# Lichess vs chess.com blitz ratings

Tags: rating

On chess.com I have a blitz rating that hovers around 1000, but on lichess my tournament blitz rating is around 1500 and I can go toe-to-toe with 1600 players. Are they using the same rating systems? Which rating system coheres more to standard chess ELO?

Answer (score 1):

The average blitz rating on chess.com is [1090](https://www.chess.com/livechess/players?type=Blitz)
The average blitz rating on lichess is around [1600](http://en.lichess.org/stat/rating/distribution/blitz)
So that looks just about right. chess.com is closer to Fide.

Comment: What makes chess.com's closer to FIDE?

Comment: I think it's partly because FIDE and chess.com start new users at 1200 and lichess starts them at 1500